# Is there a way to set the comparative in a WHERE clause to IS NULL or IS NOT NULL based on a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm no SQL expert and this has me stumped.

I have a stored procedure that I'm calling. I pass it a variable named @Requested which is used as a boolean.

What I'm trying:

```
SELECT 
    ID 
FROM 
    SomeTable
WHERE 
    Requested = CASE @Requested WHEN 0 THEN IS NULL WHEN 1 THEN IS NOT NULL END
;
```

I get errors in SQL Server Management Studio stating `Incorrect syntax near 'IS'`

The above code works if I do `THEN 'some string'`, obviously.

I've done this as `Requested CASE`... and `Requested = CASE`

Essentially what I want is

```
Requested IS NULL
```

OR

```
Requested IS NOT NULL
```

based on what value is passed in as @Requested.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use both conditions in the `WHERE` clause via an `OR` statement.  This creates a condition where the appropriate logic is used based on the value of the `@Requested` variable.

```
Select   ID 
From     SomeTable
Where    ((@Requested = 0  And Requested Is Null) 
    Or    (@Requested = 1  And Requested Is Not Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since T-SQL has limited support for `boolean` data you're stuck with something clumsy like:

```
case when @Requested = 0 then
  ( case when Requested is NULL then 1 else 0 end )
  else
  ( case when Requested is not NULL then 1 else 0 end )
  end = 1
```

Note that the result of the `CASE` is a value that needs to be used, e.g. compared to `1`.

Alternatively, you could move up some of the decision making prior to the query:

```
declare @IfNull as Int = case when @Requested = 0 then 1 else 0 end;
declare @IfNotNull as Int = 1 - @IfNull;

select ...
  where case Requested is NULL then @IfNull else @IfNotNull end = 1;
```